# Datetimepicker`s slowness

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I would like to ask you for advice.
On one page I have many jQuery UI datepicker`s. They are visible in Bootstrap Modal when user click on button. 
Unfortunately  this page is loading very slow(Especially in IE8). I know that datepicker in IE8 is causing slowness but sometime I receive that script stop working.

This is my datetimepicker in Knockout like a custom bindingHandlers

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datetimepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datetimepicker(options);//Line 5

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datetimepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
           current = $(element).datetimepicker("getDate");
        if (value - current !== 0) {
          // LINE 23  $(element).datetimepicker("setDate", value);  
        }
    }
};
```

I comment Line 23 because before I had the same issue with performance. But then I had the picker like that

```
<input data-bind="datetimepicker: date,datepickerOptions: { minDate: new Date() }"/>
```

When I comment it everything works great.

Now I change the  do (because I want to have visible datepicker when the modal is shown) and I have the same issue.
When I comment LINE 5 there is no slowness but also my datepicker is not vissible.

Can I call the binding of the datepicker's when user click on button to see the Modal? In this way the binding for datepicker's woudn't be initialized during the page loading?
If I change the jQuery UI datepicker to bootstrap datepicker, there will be some changes in performance?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially "lazily" initialize your datepicker's. For example, to go along with your existing `datepicker` binding, you could create a `lazyDatepicker` binding.

Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.lazyDatepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //keep the field's value in sync until the datepicker binding has been initialized
        var updater = ko.computed(function() {
            var options = ko.unwrap(allBindingsAccessor()),
                value = $.datepicker.formatDate(options.dateFormat || "mm/dd/yy", ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));

            $(element).val(value);
        });

        //use "one" so this only fires a single time on initial focus
        $(element).one("focus", function() {
            //binding will now keep value in sync
            updater.dispose();

            //apply the actual datepicker
            ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, {
                datepicker: valueAccessor,
                datepickerOptions: function() { return allBindingsAccessor.get("datepickerOptions"); }
            })
        });
    }
};
```

Really this just applies the `datepicker` binding when the field is focused. I also put some logic in there to keep the field up-to-date with the model until the datepicker is actually initialized (the `updater` computed).

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/GvLfV/

Comment: Yes definitely the lazyDatepicker binding helps. Unfortunately if I change the <input/> to the <div></div>(In this way datepicker is always visible not only on click) there is nothing and I cannot see the datepicker